# pointers pointing to array of integers

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

Here,I have some Doubt with the output.

Why the Output is same ?

```
   int (*r)[10];
   printf("r=%p  *r=%p\n",r,*r);
   return 0;
```

Platform-    GCC   UBUNTU 10.04

Comment: What output do you get? How does that compare to the output that you expect to get?

Comment: Here's the output     r=0x427ff4  *r=0x427ff4    which are same

Comment: See also http://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/the_ksplice_pointer_challenge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Name of the array decays to an pointer to its first element.

```
   int (*r)[10];
```

Is an pointer to an array of `10` integers.
`r` gives you the pointer itself.

This pointer to the array must be dereferenced to access the value of each element.
So contrary to what you think `**r` and not `*r` gives you access to the first element in the array.
`*r` gives you address of the first element in the array of integers, which is same as `r`

Important to note here that:
**Arrays are not pointers**

But expressions involving array name sometimes behave as pointer when those being used as name of the array would not make sense.

Comment: And if I'm correct- the expression `*r` has an lvalue of type `int[10]`, but is then converted to `int*` by the means of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: Also, "`**r` and `*r` gives you access to the first element in the array" is confusing...

Answer (score 4):

You would better understand if you look at the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int (*r)[10] = &a;

    printf("r=%p  *r=%p  *(r+0)=%p  *(r+1)=%p\n", r, *r, *(r+0), *(r+1));
    printf("sizeof(int)=%d \n", sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
r=0xbfeaa4b4  *r=0xbfeaa4b4  *(r+0)=0xbfeaa4b4  *(r+1)=0xbfeaa4dc
sizeof(int)=4
```

Observations / Point(s)-to-note:

- **_DO_NOT_** de-reference a pointer which has not yet made to point to an address. So in your program `int (*r)[10];` was de-referenced without being assigned to a memory area. This is not acceptable.
- If you see the output - *r is same as *(r+0) which is same as r (only w.r.t this case)
- If you see the output for *(r+0) and *(r+1) it is 40 bytes (0xbfeaa4dc - 0xbfeaa4b4 = sizeof(int) * size of the array (which is 10 in this case). So when you increment a pointer to a particular type, it gets incremented to sizeof(type) bytes!
- the other worth-notable points about a pointer-to-an-array-of-integers are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572158/size-of-array-of-pointers/8572754#8572754)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Remember that when an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" appears in most contexts, it will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and its value will be the address of the first element in the array.  The exceptions to this rule are when the array expression is an operand of either the `sizeof` or unary `&` (address-of) operands, or if the array expression is a string literal being used as an initializer in an array declaration.

Your situation is a mirror image of the following:

```
int a[10] = {0};
printf("a = %p, &a = %p\n", (void *) a, (void *) &a);
```

In the `printf` call, the expression `a` has its type converted from "10-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`" based on the rule above, and its value will be the address of the first element (`&a[0]`).  The expression `&a` has type "pointer to 10-element array of `int`", and its value will be the same as `a` (the address of the first element in the array is the same as the address of the array itself).

Your code has a bit of undefined behavior in that you're dereferencing `r` before it has been assigned to point anywhere meaningful, so you can't trust that the output is at all accurate.  We can fix that like so:

```
int a[10] = {0};
int (*r)[10] = &a;
printf("r = %p, *r = %p\n", (void *) r, (void *) *r);
```

In this case, `r == &a` and `*r == a`.

The expression `r` has type "pointer to 10-element array of `int`", and its value is the address of `a`.  The expression `*r` has type "10-element array of `int`, which is converted to "pointer to `int`", and its value is set to the address of the first element, which in this case is `a[0]`.  Again, the *values* of the two expressions are the same.